# What's a "variable-length format" mean?

Tags: variables, midi

Sorry for asking a basic question.

After I've understand the structure of wav file, I move on to understanding the structure of midi file.

While reading this https://github.com/colxi/midi-parser-js/wiki/MIDI-File-Format-Specifications documentation about midi files.

The part of where it showcased a table of "Value" and "Variable-length" is what I couldn't understand.

How did `C8` became `8148` in variable-length?

How did the hex `100000` became `C08000` in variable-length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the variable-length encoding, 7 bits per byte are used for the actual data. So to encode a value that has more than 7 bits, you have to split it into as many 7-bit parts as necessary, and then add the 1 MSB to all except the last one:

```
            11001000   original value
        1    1001000   7-bit parts
1 0000001  0 1001000   add signal bit
 10000001   01001000   encoded bytes
```

Comment: It took 3 hour to understand what's written here, but it all works out when I tried it on a paper.